# How do you delete a certain string from a text file and eliminate all its whitespace?

Tags: java

How do you delete a certain string from a text file and eliminate all its whitespace? For example, I want to delete the word "fruit" in every line of the text file.

```
fruit          apple
fruit   banana
fruit        strawberry
fruit      peach
```

The result of the text file should look like this:

```
apple
banana
strawberry
peach
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried to solve this yourself? If yes, include your code and explain where you are stuck. If no, then Stackoverflow is not the right place for this question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the file in this way, we can read the file into a stream and then use a regex replacement on every line:

```java
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"));
lines.map(x -> x.replaceFirst("^fruit\\s+", ""))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You should close `lines`.  See [Files.lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path))